# onResume() and onRestart() not called when come back to APP from home screen

Tags: android

I am new to Android. And currently building a simple game for Android.

My problem is when press the home button, it calls onPause(), sometimes it calls both onPause() and onStop(). However, when I try to go back to the game(by clicking the icon in home screen), neither onResume() or onRestart() is called. The game keeps rendering, but I can not interact with the game. The touch event is not working. When I try to touch the button, nothing happens and after few second, it says "not responding", then I have to force close.

BTW. I also noticed that when going out to the home screen, the surfaceDestroyed() function in MainGamePanel is called. I thought this function will block the thread, but actually the thread is still running when in home screen.

Can someone tells me why the onRestart() or onResume() is not firing and why the touch event is not working after coming back to the game from home screen?

Thank you very much.

I override onStop(), onPause(), onResume and onRestart() to output a message in log when the function is called:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Below is the code of my Activity and surface view.
I have a ActivityMainGame extends Activity:

```
public class ActivityMainGame extends Activity 
{
    private MainGamePanel mainGamePanel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_game);

        Log.w(TAG, "Creating the game");

        //set our MainGamePanel as the view
        mainGamePanel = new MainGamePanel(this);
        setContentView(mainGamePanel);
    }
}
```

And I created a MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, this class starts a thread to render stuff on canvas:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
    private MainGameThread thread;

    public MainGamePanel(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // create the game loop thread
        thread = new MainGameThread(getHolder(), this);

        // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        {
            thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try
            {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

As Adil's request, I put the error message in logcat. These are messages when my game is forced close:

```
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58): ANR in com.myslotgame (com.myslotgame /.ActivityMainGame)
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58): Load: 0.52 / 0.19 / 0.18
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58): CPU usage from 551359ms to 51ms ago:
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   system_server: 4% = 3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5766 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   adbd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 55 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 17 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1625 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1201 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 77 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   rild: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):   com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):  +myslotgame: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58):  -myslotgame: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
03-11 15:04:21.491: E/ActivityManager(58): TOTAL: 7% = 6% user + 1% kernel + 0% irq + 0% softirq
```

Comment: When you return to the game after pressing HOME, does `onCreate()` get called again?

Comment: no, the onCreate() only call the first time.

Comment: Same problem here, neither `onRestart()` nor `onCreate()`, `onResume()`... are called after `onStop()`. So weird, unfortunately no answer yet about this problem. Any news on your side?

Answer (score 0):

`onStop()` is not guaranteed to be called, as Android may sometimes have to end the game prematurely while it is in the background without prior notice, but `onPause()` will always be called! So, in the `onPause()` method, perform actions you would do if it was stopping, such as ending a rendering thread, but you can also place an if statement like `if (isFinishing())` and perform actions you would do if the activity is actually ending.
Note: you can only use the `isFinishing()` method if your activity extends the `Activity` class, your `ActivityMainGame` class in this instance.

Comment: Thanks you. Yes, the onPause() is always called. Do you mean I need to end or pause the thread when onPause() is called, so when Next time I coming back to the game, the onResume() can be called? I thought even if I don't pause the thread, the onResume() should be called anyway.

Comment: Correct, onResume() will be called whether yo actually pause the thread or not. You should therefore pause the thread in onPause() and start a new one in onResume(). Because variables in a game, such as x and y locations are preserved if the activity isn't finishing, you can safely do this. But, in onPause(), you can check if the activity is actually finishing with isFinishing(), where you can save variables like high scores, times, etc..

Comment: Ok, I will what you told me to do in onPause(). But the problem is that, currently, when I come back from home screen, the onResume() is not called, is that because the activity is finished? If so, should onRestart() be called?

Comment: `onResume()` should always be called upon resuming an activity, whether it be from returning from the home screen, turning screen on from a standby mode, or some other way. I wouldn't use `onRestart()` personally. Setup components in `onCreate()`, activate and start the thread in `onResume()`, and kill it in `onPause()`. Within `onPause()`, check if the activity is finishing with `if(isFinishing() {}` and execute an methods, such as saving high scores, within the braces ( `{}` ).

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you go to home screen the onPause and onStop and onDestroy will be called. Can you post the logcat after you force to close.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the Log is like this when force close.
03-11 14:36:20.081: I/dalvikvm(792): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-11 14:36:20.081: I/dalvikvm(792): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Comment: sorry for the format, I don't know how to format message in comment

Comment: Actually, the onDestroy() is not called, I have just check this.

Comment: I have post the errors in the bottom of the main question post. Thanks

Comment: Still not working, It seems that the surfaceCreated() is only called for the first time initializing the view, when resuming from home screen, the onResume() is not called, neither the surfaceCreated()

Comment: I did created a pause flag in thread, refer to Adam's reply, I think I am manage to pause the thread in onPause(), but the onResume() still not fired when resuming. So current, when coming back to the game, everything is frozen.

Comment: then in the loop thread create a pause flag: `if(!pause)  {//do your stuff here}`  Finally in the onPause and onResume of the activity set the pause flag:  `onPause(){  super onPause;  pause=true;}`  `onResume(){  super onResume();  pause=false;}`